# How to get an image to stretch horizontally within a Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, pictures

I have Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365.  I have an image I am trying to paste inside a Word document.  This image goes inside a table within the Word Document.  The image is a horizontal filled rectangle box as so:

[simple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73L3P.png)

In some cases, I would like to stretch this horizontally (but not vertically) to be of varying length.  However when I stretch to get larger horizontally, instead of the image stretching, I see padded white background.  If I were stretch vertically, it does stretch.  If I were to move the image further right in the table, a larger portion of the non-white background would be visible, however, I would like the image to be the same size regardless of where in the table I place it.

Is this something with tables and columns where the size is constrained or automatic cropping is taking place?

Yes if I place it outside the table, the image appears as I would expect it.  So I want the image to perhaps span multiple columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I will submit one possible solution which seems to work for me.  I would like to know the "correct" way to do it.

If I go into Picture Format/Wrap Text and select Behind Text I see the image in full and can resize it as I desire.

I guess the default behavior (In Line with Text) did not meet my needs

Comment: "in line" probably honors margins/indents/etc.